# What does ref and node refer to in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux, ref

I'm learning react-redux from the [docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) and don't see what the below means. What is the ref part referring to? And node? This ref isn't used anywhere from I see. Does the ref refer to the child component's node (the input) on the DOM after it gets rendered? If so, why not just refer to the input directly?

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addTodo } from '../actions'

let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
  let input

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (!input.value.trim()) {
          return
        }
        dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
        input.value = ''
      }}>
        <input ref={node => {
          input = node
        }} />
        <button type="submit">
          Add Todo
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
AddTodo = connect()(AddTodo)

export default AddTodo
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [ref callback attribute](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute), and its purpose is to gain "direct access" to the DOM element/class components. Using a ref you may `focus` an input box, get it's value directly or access a method of class component.

In this case it's purpose is to get/change the input's value, by assigning a reference to the input variable (the `let input`) - see comments in code.

```
let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
  let input // the input variable which will hold reference to the input element

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (!input.value.trim()) { // using the input variable
          return
        }
        dispatch(addTodo(input.value)) // using the input variable
        input.value = ''
      }}>
        <input ref={node => {
          input = node // assign the node reference to the input variable
        }} />
        <button type="submit">
          Add Todo
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: if I didn't want to use refs, would I have been able to pass down the dispatch function somewhere and trigger it using onChange for the input?

Comment: If you just want the value in the redux store, you can do something like this - `<input onChange={ (e) => dispatch(addTodo(e.target.value)) }`.

Comment: so then what's the benefit of using refs?

Comment: @mangocaptain the benefit is that you can access the input on form submit via the ref. How would you access the input on form submit?

Comment: Is using `ref` on the input the best practice for taking inputs on a react-redux app?

Comment: Nope. Use the onChange or onInput events with a handler. The ref is needed when you want do DOM related things, like focusing the input or copy to clipboard.